# GMT-0400 (EDT) Showing up after I print date in javascript

Tags: javascript

When I print out a date in javascript it adds GMT-0400 (EDT) to the end of it, is there a way I can cut this off? I'm using

```
date=Date()
document.write(date)
```

To get the date and time but I dont want the trailing GMT-0400 (EDT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `var date = new Date();`  `Date` is a constructor and should be used with the `new` keyword.
2. You need to format it.  The display, by default, is that full string.

You can use the [Date API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to build a string, or one of the [various](https://github.com/timrwood/moment) [date](http://www.datejs.com/) [formatting](http://sugarjs.com/features#date) libraries, or even just manipulate it like a string (since it is):

```
var date = new Date();
document.write(date.split('-')[0]);
```

Also, you really shouldn't use `document.write` for a bunch of reasons, but I digress since your question was not about that.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just get the appropriate parts out of the `date` object:

```
var date = new Date();

[date.toDateString(), date.toLocaleTimeString()].join(' ');
// "Wed Oct 03 2012 12:13:56"
```